# ImportError: No module named helpers (Python 2.7.12- Windows 10)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am having a problem running below code in python;

```
from helpers import process_titanic_line
print(process_titanic_line(lines[0]))
```

The error which I am getting is;

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-56917437b562> in <module>()
  1 #NOT WORKING
  2 
----> 3 from helpers import process_titanic_line
  4 print(process_titanic_line(lines[0]))

ImportError: No module named helpers
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a file named `helpers.py` in the same folder? I'm guessing not. `helpers` is not part of Python so it's trying to import a user-specific module and is unable to locate it.

Comment: Please give some more context, like, if there is a helpersmodule in your project etc..

Comment: Hi Suever and Shamil, thank you for the quick response. I uploaded the helpers.py and now error is different. I didn't upload the helpers.py file before.

Comment: The error is;                                                                              ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)...............             ----> 4 print(process_titanic_line(lines[0]))
C:\Users\dell.......................................                                                    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,1,Allen, Miss. Elisabeth Walton'

Answer (score 0):

I had to upload helpers module to python. I did it by uploading helpers.py file for the project. I would like to thank all who contributed to the discussion.